# Show that if $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges, then $\sum_n a_n^2$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that if $\sum_n |a_n|$ converges, then $\sum_n a_n^2$ converges
>   whenever all $a_n$ are in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Lemma:** I have already proved that if $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ converge absolutely, then $\sum_{n,m} a_n b_m$ converges absolutely.

Let's take $b_n:=a_n$ for all $n$. From the above lemma we know that $\sum_{n,m} a_n a_m$ converges absolutely. Since $\sum_n a_n^2 \le \sum_{n,m} |a_n a_m|$, by comparison we get that $\sum_n a_n^2$ is convergent.

Now I have two questions:

1) Is the above derivation correct?

2) Is it possible to deduce this without refering to the Lemma?

Comment: Should the summand be $a_nb_m,$ perhaps?

Comment: @CameronBuie I've chosen $b_n:=a_n$

Comment: I mean in the Lemma.

Comment: @CameronBuie Of course you're right. Corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addressing only question 2: If $\sum|a_n|$ converges, then $|a_n|\to0$ so eventually we must have $|a_n|<1$. Let us assume (Wlog) that $|a_n|<1$ for all $n$. Then $a_n^2=|a_n|^2<|a_n|$ for all $n$ so we can apply the comparison test.

Comment: So simple! Sometimes I feel very dumb...

Comment: Don't! My guess is the lemma you proved sort of engulfs/includes this argument.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way: For any $N$, by looking at the diagonal terms we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |a_n|\right)^2.$$ Since the left hand side is nonnegative and the right hand side tends to a limit as $N\rightarrow \infty$, $\sum_{n}a_n^2$ must converge.